# socket.io callback don't work when emitting to room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to use callback function on the server when I emit to a room. In the room there is only 1 device that has a specific channel number. I can emit to it but can not get the callback to work.

server

```
 socket.to(userId).emit('request-api', options, (response: any) => {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

client

```
socket.on('request-api', (arg1, callback) => {
      console.log(arg1);

      callback({
        status: 'ok',
      });
    });
```

Is there a way that I can have the server to emit event and get callback. Nodejs project

Comment: What do you want the callback to do? What do you mean "and get callback"??

Comment: If you want the client to send back an answer, you should `socket.send` something